# Xcode: GPS navigation offline with googlemapAPI or another?

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps, navigation, gps

I need to create an iphone application that
: Offline Travel Guide Navigation with GPS at limited location(One place,but wide area)
: contain a map which has a navigation point
: when you arrive to some area like when I arrive to the temple, program will show content that contains a detail of the temple
: can be show that what area are you already have been there and not yet.

1.Is it possible to do this with googlemap API or another service or another way such as (create my own map,use an map image on the background and create a moving point)?

2.Is it better if I change to online application ?

thx for your advice,..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you want to have the ability to designate an area that will then be cached from google maps so you can then take the connection off-line and still view that map area.

If that is what you are asking, then that is defiantly possible - See the iOS app called 'Trails'. This does just that. As to how it does it, I am not sure. I would guess that it pretends it is somewhere and then get's the map API to retrieve that data, then stores the cached data somewhere where it can be called back as needed.

Good luck.